# How to replace Ubuntu with Windows 10 without cloud backup or losing any data

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, windows, backup

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 in it. I want to use Unity 3D, so I would need to install windows. I think of replacing ubuntu with Windows but don't want to lose any data. I don't want to use a cloud platform. Is there any way I can backup my ubuntu data.

I have made a partition for windows also

Comment: " The backup method should work on windows if it is an application"  wrong place to ask this.

Comment: Copy the files somewhere that isn't in the cloud; we cannot know what local storage you have.

Comment: okay. Can I get the files from windows

Answer (score 1):

1. Transfer all data you need from ubuntu to usb stick formatted in FAT32 (to use with any OS) ==> install windows ==> copy data from usb->windows;
2. Make separate partition in FAT32 and copy data there. Install windows and do not touch that partition. Windows should see this partition as dick D:\ of smthg like that;
3. Make FTP server in your local network for backup data.

Comment: 3rd and 2nd Option sounds better. Trying second